# Underscore, turn list of objects into array of object values

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

So I have a list of objects like

```
 var options =   
 [{"car" : "red"},{"house": "green"},{"dog":"bark"}]
```

That I am trying to turn into an array of values from that, so it would look like this:

```
["red","green","bark"]
```

Here is my (non-working) attempt

```
newUrl = _.each(options, function(obj){
                    return _.values(obj);
                });
                console.log(newUrl);
```

So iterate through each object and fetch the value. The iteration works, the .values does not seem to be working how I though it would though.

Comment: `each` does not return anything.  perhaps you need `.reduce`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without underscore, you can do:

```
var colors = options.map(function(item) { 
    return item[Object.keys(item)[0]] 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need underscore for this, just Array.prototype.map();

```
var newUrl = options.map(function (item) {
    return item[Object.keys(item)[0]];
});
```